# How to add entries every time a button is pressed

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am making a mobile app using Xamarin Forms and I am writing all of my code including the visual aspects in c# (in the .cs files).
Essentially I need to be able to add a new entry every time a button is pressed and then get the text entered into said entry.

Right now I can create a new Entry and give it a name that I can use to reference it:

```
private Entry entry1;
Layout.Children.Add(entry1 = new Entry
{
//entry code
});

//when some button is pressed
string entry1Text = entry1.Text;
```

I want to make it so that every time the user presses a button, it creates a new entry, but I also need to be able to get the text from it. How can I  make it so that it creates a new entry with a new name like entry2, entry3, etc... without manually writing out like 10 entries and then making them visible? I need to do this because I don't know how many entries the user will add (could be more than 10).

```
int numberOfEntries = 1;
void addEntry_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string entryNumber = numberOfEntries.ToString();

    //the following 2 lines are what doesn't work with the name of an entry, but is what I want to do
    private Entry entry + entryNumber;
    Layout.Children.Add(entry + entryNumber = new Entry
    {
        //entry code
    });

    numberOfEntries+=1;
}

//some button is pressed
string entryText = (entry + entryNumber).Text;
```

The problem is I can't add a number to the name of an entry like entry +"2"
Is this even possible for me to do?

Comment: So you want to identify Entries with a specific name pattern right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to keep a separate data structure to track your controls, like this

```
Dictionary<string,Entry> entries = new Dictionary<string,Entry>();

private void AddEntry(string name)
{
  var entry = new Entry();
  myLayout.Children.Add(entry);
  entries.Add(name,entry);
}
```

then you can get their value like this

```
var text = entries["entryA"].Text;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got it working by using your solution and by also changing `myLayout.Children.Add(entry);` to `myLayout.Children.Add(entry, Constraint.Constant(0);` because I was getting an error along the lines of "the call was ambiguous."